# Prove $a/b+b/a$ for $a$ and $b$ natural is only natural for $a=b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

Is it possible to prove that for any natural $a,b$ the value of $a/b+b/a$ will not be natural with exception $a=b$?

Comment: It is a homework question [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-b-b-a-equals-an-integer-for-any-a-b-nonzero-positive-integers-if-and-only-if-a.595317/).

Comment: **Hint** $ $ If $\,\large x\in\Bbb Q\,$ then $ \large x+1/x = n \iff x^2-nx+1= 0\,\Rightarrow\, x = \pm1\,$ by the Rational Root Test

Answer (score 10):

$$\begin{align}
{a\over b}+{b\over a}=k&\implies a^2-kba+b^2=0\\
&\implies a=\left(k\pm\sqrt{k^2-4}\over2\right)b\\
&\implies\sqrt{k^2-4}\in\mathbb{N}\\
&\implies k=2\\
&\implies a=b
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ relatively prime (if they are not, just simplify the fractions until they are). We have
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab}$$
you're asking that
$a^2 + b^2 = kab$ for some $k$ natural.

This would mean that $b^2 = a(kb-a)$ is divided by $a$, which is absurd since $b$ isn't. The only possibility is $a=b=1$, which implies $a=b$ if we don't assume they are relatively prime.

Comment: I think you should explicitly show that $b^2$ cannot be divisible by $a$ if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and not both equal to 1.

Comment: If $b^2$ is divided by $a$, it contains all the prime factors of $a$. But since $b$ and $b^2$ have the same prime factors, this is absurd because $a$ and $b$ have no common prime factors.

Comment: Ok, but you should put that info into your answer, rather than adding it in a comment. Even better: see if you can prove it without relying on the rather heavy machinery of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: This is a very common technique in arithmetic proofs, and I believe that implication is pretty obvious. About your other statement, I guess it can be done, but I think that would just confuse the OP.

Comment: @PM2Ring, Euclid's lemma (if $a \mid c d$ with $\gcd(a, c) = 1$ implies $a \mid d$) is enough (take $c = d = b$). Not "heavy"...

Comment: @vonbrand: That's exactly what I was thinking. :) Of course, proving Euclid's lemma is a little tricky too (I usually do it via Bézout's identity), and of course once you have Euclid's lemma it's fairly easy to prove the FTA, but I still think using Euclid's is nicer than using FTA, when you can get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a^2+b^2=kab,\,k\in\mathbb{N}$. Define $d:=\text{gcd}\left(a,\,b\right),\,a':=\tfrac{a}{d}\,b':=\tfrac{b}{d}$ so $a'^2+b'^2=ka'b'$. If $p$ is a prime factor of $a'$, then $p|b'^2=ka'b'-a'^2$ so $p|b'$. But $\text{gcd}\left(a',\,b'\right)=1$, so no prime divides $a'$. Hence $a'=1$; similarly $b'=1,\,a=b=d,\,k=2$.

Comment: Where does the 2 come from in $2kab$ ?

Answer (score -1):

That's easy. $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a} = \frac{ a^2 + b^2 }{ab}$ So that $a/b+b/a$ is a natural number means $ a^2 +b^2 = k \cdot ab $ for some natural number k. We know the equation $x^2 -kx +1 =0$ has two integer roots if and only if $k=2$. To satisfy the condition, a should be equal to b.

Comment: How do you prove the statement on the quadratic equation ?